# Move/Modify workspace switcher popup

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, 18.10, workspace-switcher

I use Ubuntu 18.10 and I'm wondering if there is a way to somehow move the workspace switcher pop-up elsewhere, or modify it in some way. It is somewhat distracting when positioned in the middle of the screen.
I like the way it is implemented in distributions like FreeBSD or Lubuntu but I don't feel like switching just because of that.
There's a gnome extension that removes the pop-up entirely, but I'd rather have information about which workspace I am positioned on.

Comment: Nice answer below, but just providing another possible approach. Another extension, Workspace Indicator, puts the active workspace number or name in the top bar. That way, you would be hinted there about on what workspace you are, except, of course, when an application is full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the Workspace Switcher Pop up location from center of the screen requires editing the gnome-shell core files which is very hard.

Instead you can little bit tweak the sizes and colors.

Ubuntu 18.10 with default User-Shell theme.
[image]

after Tweaking
[image]

to tweak it, i have edited the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`

Original Content

```
/* Workspace Switcher */
.workspace-switcher-group {
  padding: 12px; }

.workspace-switcher-container {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.workspace-switcher {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  spacing: 8px; }

.ws-switcher-active-up, .ws-switcher-active-down {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.4);
  color: #ffffff;
  background-size: 32px;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.ws-switcher-active-up {
  background-image: url("ws-switch-arrow-up.svg"); }

.ws-switcher-active-down {
  background-image: url("ws-switch-arrow-down.svg"); }

.ws-switcher-box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.1);
  background: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.1);
  border-radius: 6px; }

.osd-window,
.resize-popup, .switcher-list, .workspace-switcher-container {
  color: #F7F7F7;
  background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.975);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

Edited Content

```
/* Window Cycler */
.cycler-highlight {
  border: 5px solid #E95420; }

/* Workspace Switcher */
.workspace-switcher-group {
  padding: 12px; }

.workspace-switcher-container {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.workspace-switcher {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  spacing: 8px; }

.ws-switcher-active-up, .ws-switcher-active-down {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-size: 32px;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.ws-switcher-active-up {
  background-image: url("ws-switch-arrow-up.svg"); }

.ws-switcher-active-down {
  background-image: url("ws-switch-arrow-down.svg"); }

.ws-switcher-box {
  height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.1);
  background: green;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.osd-window,
.resize-popup, .switcher-list, .workspace-switcher-container {
  color: #F7F7F7;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

you can make your customization based on above.

Answer (score 1):

Just need install ***Open GNOME Shell extensions website*** in you firefox or chrome. And install ***Disable Workspace Switcher Popup*** [plugin](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/959/disable-workspace-switcher-popup/).

Comment: this was exactly was I was looking for, thanks!